# How to make an absolutely positioned element have the same size as another element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout like this:

```css
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .link {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .info {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #263238;
        color: #1DE9B6;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      
      .link:hover .info {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
    
    .col-md-3 {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="link">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="info">Info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When the layout gets small, and only one column is displayed horizontally, the div which is supposed to show on hover gets as big as the column, but I only want it to be as big as the fluid image. How would I need to achieve this?

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/gKVwLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add display: inline-block to the link element

```
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can also add `d-inline-block position-relative` classes on the .link elements .

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #263238;
    color: #1DE9B6;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .link:hover .info {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

.col-md-3 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="link">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="info">Info</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```